# Magento : Product Attribute Value Not Getting In Custom Model

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, model, custom-attributes

I am trying to get some attribute value for product in my custom created model. However some values are getting and some not. Also those attributes values are getting for other products, but not for one product only. I checked in back-end , but values are stored for that product in back-end.

Please help me to get attribute value. Thanks

Comment: Please remove cache and do re-indexing.

Comment: I tried. But again bot showing any value. however other atrributes value are showing, but some attributes values are not showing.